# Is なびっくる a variant of びっくり

Tags: colloquial-language

I heard this term なびっくる live on http://www.fm-totsuka.com/
I checked http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/ and http://ejje.weblio.jp/ but could not find any entry for なびっくる, https://translate.google.com/#ja/en/%E3%81%AA%E3%81%B3%E3%81%A3%E3%81%8F%E3%82%8B has it as "surprised". Is なびっくる a variant of びっくり?

Comment: 「なびっくる」という言葉はないと思います・・・

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No なびっくる is not a variant of びっくり. Perhaps you've misheard something. Since you've heard it on the radio, is there a possibility that you've heard an ad of ナビクル (There's an [ad library](https://www.navikuru.jp/satei/navikuru_satei/radio/))?

Comment: Thanks! You are spot on! It was the add - it was almost like the second in the link you provided. I wonder how Google translate got it as "Surprised".